# How efficient is a details table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

At my job, we have pseudo-standard of creating one table to hold the "standard" information for an entity, and a second table, named like 'TableNameDetails', which holds optional data elements.  On average, for every row in the main table will have about 8-10 detail rows in it.

My question is: What kind of performance impacts does this have over adding these details as additional nullable columns on the main table?

Comment: Additional nullable columns for 8-10 rows?  That leads to huge duplication of what you're calling "standard" information.  Are you sure it's rows, not columns?

Comment: Yes, it's row.  Each detail table has one column for the foreign key to the main table, one column to hold a string that represents the name of the data element(like 'name', or 'StartDate'), and one column to hold the actual detail.

Comment: Lott: Please do not comment on your own question.  Please UPDATE your question to be correct and complete.  After updating the question, feel free to delete your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are describing is an Entity-Attribute-Value design. They have their place in the world, but they should be avoided like the plague unless absolutely necessary. The analogy I always give is that they are like drugs: in small quantities and in select circumstances they can be beneficial. Too much will kill you. Their performance will be awful and will not scale and you will not get any sort of data integrity on the values since they are all stored as strings.

So, the short answer to your question: if you never need to query for specific values nor ever need to make a columnar report of a given entity's attributes nor care about data integrity nor ever do anything other than spit the entire wad of data for an entity out as a list, they're fine. If you need to actually use them however, whatever query you write will not be efficient.

Answer (score 5):

8-10 detail *rows* or 8-10 detail *columns* ?

If its rows, then you're mixing apples and oranges as a one-to-many relationship cannot be flatten out into columns.

If is columns, then you're talking vertical partitioning. For large and very large tables, moving seldom referenced columns into Extra or Details tables (ie partition the columns vertically into 'hot' and 'cold' tables) can have significant and event huge performance benefits. Narrower table means higher density of data per page, in turn means less pages needed for frequent queries, less IO, better cache efficiency, all goodness.

Mileage may vary, depending on the average width of the 'details' columns and how 'seldom' the columns are accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Remus on all the "depends", but would just add that after choosing this design for a table/entity, you must **also** have a good process for determining what is "standard" and what is "details" for an entity.

Misplacing something as a detail which should be standard is probably the worst thing.  Because you can't require a row to exist as easily as requiring a column to exist (big complex trigger code).  Setting a default on a type of row is a **lot** harder (big complex constraint code).  And indexing is also not easy either (sparse index, maybe?).

Misplacing something as a standard which should be a detail is less of a mistake, just taking up extra row space and potentially not being able to have a meaningful default.

If your details are very weakly structured, you could consider using an XML column for the "details" and still be able to query them using XPath/XQuery.

As a general rule, I would **not** use this pattern for every entity table, but only entity tables which have certain requirements and usage patterns which fit this solution's benefits well.

Answer (score 1):

Is your details table an entity value table? In that case, yes you are asking for performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different data models - a domain specific one for the "standard" and a key/value one for the "extended" information.

I dislike key/value tables except when absolutely required. They run counter to the concept of an SQL database and generally represent an attempt to shoehorn object data into a data store that can't conveniently handle it.

If some of the extended information is very often NULL you can split that column off into a separate table. But if you do this to two different columns, put them in *separate* tables, not the same table.